# How to use filterBy in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am putting together a simple book sorter app and I am having some trouble using the `filterBy` filter. The filter works fine for filtering the `non-fiction` `genre` but for some reason it does not work for `fiction`. I want to display the book titles and authors, and then in the input field, filter through the list of books being displayed by genre. So if I write fiction in the input field, it should only display the fiction books. This is what my view looks like:

```
       <div id="app">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
              <div id="input">
               <input type="text" v-model="genre" placeholder="Search fiction/non-fiction">
            </div>
             <div id="display-books" v-for=" book in books | filterBy genre in 'genre' ">
               <span>Title: {{book.title}}</span>
               <span>Author: {{book.author}}</span>      
        </div>  
    </div>
```

And here is my `app.js`:

```
var appData = { 
  title: 'Book Sorter',
  filters: 'Search filter',
  filtertext: '* only show title if book is available',
  genre: '',
  books:
    [
      {genre: "fiction", title: "The Hobbit", author: "J.R.R Tolkien", available: false},
      {genre: "non-fiction", title: "Homage to Catalonia", author: "George Orwell", available: true},
      {genre: "non-fiction", title: "The Tipping Point", author: "Malcolm Gladwell", available: false},
      {genre: "fiction", title: "Lord of the Flies", author: "William Golding", available: true},
      {genre: "fiction", title: "The Call of the Wild", author: "Jack London", available: true}   
    ]

}
new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data: appData,

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your setup, Vue's filterBy is working fine in your example. When you type `fiction`, it will show all Books because they all have the word `fiction` in the genre, meaning that: `fiction` and `non-fiction` both contains `fiction`, returning `true`.

Create a custom filter like this:

```
Vue.filter('match', function (value, input) {
  return input ? value.filter(function(item) {
     return item.genre === input ? value : null;
  }) : value;
});
```

And change selection from an input to dropdown:

```
<select v-model="genre">
    <option value="" selected>Select Genre</option> 
    <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
    <option value="non-fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
</select>
```

Here is a fiddle implementing it: https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/br8huz7c/

Comment: Would I need to use an exact match filter then?

Comment: Exactly. You can probably create a custom filter for that. However, for showing lists like this, you may want to change the input to a dropdown. This way, it will only trigger an event when the user select the desired genre.

Comment: I added a fiddle as an example. Check it out.